# How to connect fireplace.vim to browser repl

Tags: vim, clojurescript

Is it possible to connect vim.fireplace to a browser repl ? I have a setup using austin but if I try to evaluate something inside vim I get:

```
org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "setTimeout" is not defined.
```

which seems to be an indicator that the browser repl is not used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Browser repl, noderepl, rhino repl...

Checkout the docs and read about piggieback. That's how it handles the envs

https://github.com/tpope/vim-fireplace/blob/master/doc/fireplace.txt
https://github.com/cemerick/piggieback

Piggieback is included on Austin too so it should work if you :Connect to Austin and then :Piggieback with the environment you want

**Edit: example**

Read https://github.com/cemerick/austin/blob/master/README.md#usage and look at the environment that corresponds to how you started the repl. For example `:Piggieback  (cemerick.austin/repl-env)`. Look at the docs to see different repl-env that you can try.

**Edit 2: Sample project Vim nRepl and node repl**

Check out this project and the instructions in the readme for something similar for nodejs

https://github.com/joakin/cljs-node-repl/blob/master/README.md

Comment: The problem is that I have no idea what to pass as the environment.

Comment: Read https://github.com/cemerick/austin/blob/master/README.md#usage and look at the environment that corresponds to how you started the repl. For example :Piggieback  (cemerick.austin/repl-env). Look at the docs to see different repl-env that you can try.

Answer (score 4):

I found [this discussion](http://www.reddit.com/r/Clojure/comments/2kojth/vimfireplace_and_chestnut_now_working/) on Reddit to be helpful.

Specifically, I've added these commands (as suggested in the post) to my vimrc as shortcuts depending on what environment I want to connect to:

```
command! Piggie :Piggieback (cemerick.austin/exec-env)
command! Biggie :Piggieback (cemerick.austin/exec-env :exec-cmds ["open" "-ga" "/Applications/Google Chrome.app"])
command! Wiggie :Piggieback (weasel.repl.websocket/repl-env :ip "0.0.0.0" :port 9001)
```

Now, I can

1. Start repl (`lein repl` or `:Console`)
2. Start web app in repl (e.g. `(run)` when using a chestnut lein template)
3. Open cljs buffer in vim.
4. Connect to repl using commands (e.g. `:Wiggie`)
5. Evaluate expressions in my buffer, and see live changes in the browser!